# Working with 2 remote repositories

Tags: git

I've made two repos for the sake of learning git, until now I've just been pushing to one remote repo from my local one. I just made a second remote repo and want to put all my code in there. Currently my local repo has a lot of untracked files and unpushed changes. How can I get all my files from the local repo to the new remote repo?

Comment: I don't recommend creating a new repo and then trying to synchronize from another remote (because of issues with disconnected history) - it's better just to `clone`  from the existing repo. Are you able to do that or do you absolutely need to retain your existing repos?

Comment: No it's not necessary to retain the existing repo or restrict to just one local repo, I'll update the question

Answer (score 1):

Go into first-repo and create a new `remote` (say, `secondRepo`) with the URL of `second-repo`.

```
# run in first-repo
$ git add remote secondRepo <second-repo-url>
$ git fetch secondRepo
```

Now, checkout to a new branch (say, `feature`). Do `Add`, `Commit` your local changes, Push to new remote (here, `secondRepo`) branch (say, `master`).

```
$ git checkout -b feature
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m 'message'
$ git push secondRepo master
```

Now, **secondRepo**'s **master** branch has all your local files, commits/changes.